# ExcludeFromCodeCoverage Exclude Auto-Generated Code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, auto-generate, ncover

Is there a way to mark an auto-generated class as ExcludeFromCodeCoverage.  I am using that attribute in other areas and works great.  But if you open the code of the auto-generated guy and mark the classes as ExcludeFromCodeCoverage, once you re-generate that class itll be over written.

I can create partial classes in the code behind of the dbml and apply that attribute to it and it works, however, that would make for a lot of partial classes.

Comment: Can you make auto-generated class come with `partial` (like, altering generator in some way)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/features) or other AOP framework to create aspect which will apply `ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute` to specified types or namespaces:

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Class | MulticastTargets.Struct)]
[ProvideAspectRole(StandardRoles.PerformanceInstrumentation)]
public sealed class DisableCoverageAttribute : TypeLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        Type disabledType = (Type)targetElement;

        var introducedExclusion = new CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect(
              new ObjectConstruction(typeof (ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute)));

        return new[] {new AspectInstance(disabledType, introducedExclusion)};
    }
}
```

Then just apply this aspect to assembly and provide namespace which you want to exclude. During compilation PostSharp will add `ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute` to all classes in `My.AutogeneratedCode` namespace:

```
[assembly: DisableCoverage(AttributeTargetTypes="My.AutogeneratedCode.*")]
```

Sample code and explanations you can find [here](http://badecho.com/2012/03/excluding-code-coverage-with-postsharp/).